# Mongo Database not running

Tags: node.js, mongodb

PS C:\Users\Emmanuel\Desktop\node-course> \Users\Emmanuel\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe  --dbpath=/Users/Emmanuel/mongodb-data
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--dbpath=/Users/Emmanuel/mongodb-data'
try '\Users\Emmanuel\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe --help' for more information

Comment: I tried running it before and it worked, but now I simply can't figure it out...

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? What did you try running and what was the error output?